# MacOSX Express Mongoose mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27071') -- ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27071 -- works fine on CLI

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos, mongoose

I'm pretty sure I've exhausted all methods here, followed the first 3 pages of Google and near every similar question here, and I am getting sick of reading every response to this "have you downloaded MongoDB?".

YES, it is downloaded, and running, and connectable from Robo3T and CLI `mongo`.

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 4.0.2
```

YES, it was downloaded/installed using the recommended setup from source -- ie, home brew, brew services etc.

```
Jamies-MacBook-Pro:api jamiepoole$ brew services list
Name    Status  User       Plist
mongodb started jamiepoole /Users/jamiepoole/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

YES, I have tried connecting with `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, hell even the computer hostname / `Jamies-MacBook-Pro.local`

I have no doubt I'm doing something stupid or missed something simple, but I am pretty certain its not that.

```
const Database = Mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27071/myproject');
```

---

I replaced project details from the below with ... -- so this isn't a setting / in the code.

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27071] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27071]
at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/.../node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/.../node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/.../node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
name: 'MongoNetworkError',
errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
[Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

---

At this point any help at all would be amazing. Seems like such a simple error but can't find any help anywhere.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined wrong MongoDB port in your code while your CLI is connecting to the right port which 27017. You can edit the code as follows

```
const Database = Mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject');
```

Comment: F.M.L. I knew it.

Comment: Thanks. Just needed those fresh eyes.

Comment: It'd be great if you accept the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: I can't for another 5 minutes ;)